# Rabbitmq Haproxy termination states

Tags: haproxy, rabbitmq

In log of haproxy i see an cD flag. Balancer is in front of rabbitmq nodes. 
When nagios checking nodes, log looks like this: SD flag

```
[10/Nov/2014:14:48:01.190] from NAGIOS IP to Rabbitmq:5672 rabbitmq_01 SD req_size=6 resp_size=0
```

And when client connects, log looks like this: cD flag. Client connects from tomcat.

```
[10/Nov/2014:14:43:52.692] from  Client to Rabbitmq:5672 rabbitmq_-02 cD req_size=853 resp_size=686
```

If i change timeout from 200s, to 300s, then message in log looks like:

```
[10/Nov/2014:15:25:42.576] from  Client to Rabbitmq:5672 rabbitmq_02 SD req_size=937 resp_size=681
```

Cant understand how to fix timeouts, and avoid this problem about SD, cD flags.

Haproxy conf looks like this

```
defaults
    log     global
    mode    tcp
    option  tcplog
    option  dontlognull
    option redispatch
    retries 3
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  200s
    timeout server  200s

          frontend localnodes    
bind *:5673    
mode tcp    
option tcplog    
log global    
log-format [%t]\ from\ %ci:%cp\ to\ %si:%sp\
    %s\ %ts\ req_size=%U\ resp_size=%B    
default_backend rabbit
    backend rabbit
    mode tcp
    log global
    option tcplog
    option tcpka
    balance roundrobin
    server rabbitmq_01 :5672 check
    server rabbitmq_02 :5672  check
```

Comment: This won't address the server disconnects, but on your frontend, can you try enabling keepalives?

Comment: No, nothing... and something strange, log writes only when client was disconnected. Or sometimes even not writing logs at all

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen random issues with 'SD--' termination state in haproxy logs while trying to download big file which is served by apache tomcat.

The problem was fixed by increasing connectionTimeout from 5 seconds to 30 seconds in tomcat connector's configuration.

Maybe rabbitmq has some similar tunables also.